# how to check car for impending failures?

Tags: obd-ii, radiator, diagnostics, obd, inspection

My kia Sorento 2007 failed on me multiple times. Each time disabling the car and putting the driver in danger

1. harmonic balancer
2. alternator
3. radiator and water pump

in each of those failures, I had to bring the car to the mechanic and he reported and fixed the problems. there where no OBD code that I know off

my questions are:

1. how to test car and fix those particular problem and similar before
   they happen?
2. is the on board diagnostics via obd is at all helpful for these problems?
3. do they check these kind of problems at trade-in dealerships?
4. is the only way to avoid getting stranded is to drive a late model car?

Comment: Welcome to the site. What makes you think it's any of those things above? You say the car was disabled, do you mean the engine quit? Have you had the OBD codes read?

Comment: Late model cars can fail too, Drive as if your car is always about to fail on you.  Keep your options open in traffic and don't leave home unless you are prepared to be out in the weather for awhile.

Comment: Preventative maintenance is very good...

Comment: @GdD in each of those failures, I had to bring the car to the mechanic and he reported and fixed the problems, there where no OBD code that I know off

Comment: This is such a broad question. It seems to me it needs to be tightened up to cover a more specific issue and not so broad as there could be a thousand answers which still would not cover it all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you test for looming problems:

1. Harmonic balancer.  Like any other engine internals, it will rap, knock, or tick long before it fails.  Rev the engine steady in neutral at 2,000, 3,000 rpm and listen carefully for noises;  listen also when you release the pedal.  Check for noises at cold startup and at other temperatures besides fully warmed up.  Also, have the crankcase oil evaluated [by a lab](https://blog.amsoil.com/how-to-perform-oil-analysis/) for evidence of high metal content, indicating excessive wear.
2. Alternator.  Like other components driven by the accessory belt, listen for unusual noises at various engine speeds in neutral.  Use [an automotive stethoscope](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0015DLMOO) to help pinpoint faulty parts.  With the car off, connect [a voltage meter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00HE6MIJY) to the battery (should read 12.5-12.65 volts), then start the car (voltage should climb to 13.0-14.5 volts);
   stress the alternator by turning on the headlights, the radio and the air conditioning. The voltage should remain high with these circuits on. If the voltage does not change when the engine is started, if it does not get above 13 volts, or if it charges above 15 volts then the alternator may be faulty.
3. Radiator and water pump.  With the engine running and fully warmed up, scan the entire surface of the radiator with [an infrared thermometer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DMI632G).  If there are distinct cold patches, the radiator may be partially clogged.  Using [a strong flashlight](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00THMIK4A), look for corrosion, especially along any seams.  Also with the flashlight, look around the pulley of the water pump, close to the belt, for any dry coolant stains.  Listen for any gurgling sounds while driving or while the car cools in the garage.  Check coolant reservoir at cold for any slight loss of fluid over the course of a month.  Drive the car from cold to fully warm, noting the temperature gauge.  It should rise to 180-190 degrees F. within 15 minutes and maintain that temp. at highway speeds;  it should hover around 220 deg. F. in dense, stop-and-go traffic and never exceed 230 deg. F.

[An OBD scanner](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076XVQMVS) is helpful for preventive diagnostics.  It can show trouble codes that are happening and stored in the car's computer, but infrequent enough not to cause a dashboard light.

I've been driving nothing but used cars for 35 years and have never been stranded using these techniques.  Most of those cars have been older than ten years.  One of my current cars is 27 years old!

By the way, you forgot to mention tires.  You'd be amazed how many disasters I've avoided by checking the air pressure and feeling the treads with my hands once a month!